# Check Box behavior is not properly working with DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have tweaked some behavior in the Data Grid. Maintained the check box in the Template column and bind the collection from the view model. Based upon this property I would like to update the Background and foreground property of the DataGridRow. On this try check box checked is not properly update on the first click. Uncheck event is unnecessarily triggered to break this behavior. How can I overcome this issue.

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_KeyDown"   Margin="5"  HeadersVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None"
          SelectionMode="Extended"  Height="465"  BorderThickness="0" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Book Antiqua" FontWeight="Bold" RowHeight="25" ColumnWidth="*" >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#EDFFF9"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0078D7"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="30">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ledgerSelectedChk" Checked="ledgerSelectedChk_Checked_1" Unchecked="ledgerSelectedChk_Unchecked" Click="ledgerSelectedChk_Checked" BorderThickness="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

C#

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //if I comment this means all are working properly
    foreach (var item in dataGrid.SelectedItems)
    {
        (item as OrderInfo).IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you click an item it is unchecked which fires the unchecked event. Then the selectionchanged event causes the item to become checked again which fires the checked event. This probably happens so fast that you can't tell the item was unchecked, except for the event that is being triggered

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you suggest me the work around to achieve this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your scenario and found that, when you set the IsSelected items is true at the DataGridSelection changed event, Currently clicked checkbox on the datagrid row got focused and IsChecked property of the checkbox in that particular row is set as true. Hence you try to check the same checkbox, which states goes to unchecked then UnChecked event called from the framework. This is the correct behavior.

you can achieve your requirement by setting the focus to datagrid at the checkbox checked event.